# PHP: Variable changes value without seemingly any reason

Tags: php

```
$subjectDirectory = '../blogtext/';
$subjectHandle = opendir( $subjectDirectory );
$fileName = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$tempArray = explode( '-', $fileName );
$finalNum = '-'.$tempArray[1].'-';
$subjectFile;
if( $subjectHandle = opendir( '../blogtext/' ) )
{
    /* If you echo $finalNum here, you get '-0-' on the page. */
    while( false !== ( $subjectFile = readdir( $subjectHandle ) ) )
    {
        /* If you echo $finalNum here, you get '-0--0--0--0--0-' on the page. */
        if( $subjectFile != '.' && $subjectFile != '..' && !is_dir( $subjectFile ) && strpos( $subjectFile, $finalNum ) ) 
        {
            include( $subjectFile );
        }
    }
    closedir( $subjectHandle );
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is;
get -NUMBER- code from the current file name ( -0-example.php ), and then scan through the directory ( $subjectDirectory ) for the file name that begins with the same code. Then include the file.

I'm unable to do so because the $finalNum changes the code to "code 5 times in a row", so I can't find the right file to include.

Comment: `fileNum` is probably being written to by the included file.  What you are trying to do terrifies me, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because `readdir()` returns the file name only, not the full path.

Try this:
    include( $subjectDirectory . $subjectFile );

Re: /* If you echo $finalNum here, you get '-0--0--0--0--0-' on the page. */

The reason you get this output is because you are echoing $finalNum 5 times. The value of $finalNum is not changing.

**EDIT:**
I found one more issue in your `if` statement. `strpos( $subjectFile, $finalNum )` will return 0 if the $subjectFile starts with $finalNum. 
Use this instead.

```
if( $subjectFile != '.' && $subjectFile != '..' && !is_dir( $subjectFile ) && strpos( $subjectFile, $finalNum ) !== false )
```

Comment: Nope.
I'm fairly certain that everything is working ( I even tried what you suggested ).
It's just that I can't figure out why the $finalNum changes it's value.

Comment: This will get you working, but what you are trying to do here seems like problems waiting to happen. Maybe a new question stating what you want to do, how you're currently doing it, and ask for suggestions on how to restructure to make it better...

Comment: $finalNum is not changing value. It's inside a `while` loop being outputting multiple times. If you echo $finalNum inside the if, you should only see it output once.

Comment: Well, I don't.
The code doesn't get to the inside of the if statement. ( That's probably why I don't get include errors ).
I think there's something wrong with my if conditions. I'll try to debug it. Will report back shortly.

Comment: Agreed, I just updated the answer. It's around the strpos function call.

Comment: Yeah, that last edit did the trick. Thanks so much! :)
I know that my code is all spaghetti and bad and stuff, but atm I'm making this site mostly just to learn the basics of PHP, and not to make something amazing, and profitable, so I don't mind the security holes, etc.